# How do I find binary installed from AUR package?

Tags: arch-linux, binary, aur

I installed `balena-cli` from AUR (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/balena-cli/) using `yay` on my Arch box and all seemed to complete well but I can't find a `balena-cli` (or similar binary) on my system. How can I see what got installed and where the binary is? There is no `/usr/bin/balena` and:

```
$ pacman -Ql balena-cli
error: package 'balena-cli' was not found
```

**UPDATE:**

I even tried to install it manaually (without `yay`) with:

```
$ git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/balena-cli.git
$ cd balena-cli/
$ makepkg -si
```

but get:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/balena
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/balena': No such file or directory
```

while:

```
$ tar -tf balena-cli-11.30.1.tgz | grep bin
package/bin/balena
package/bin/balena-dev
```

I also checked the other archive:

```
$ tar -tf balena-cli-11.30.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz | grep "usr/bin"
usr/bin/
usr/bin/balena
```

Comment: Have you tried `pacman -Ql balena-cli`? Is there a `/usr/bin/balena`?

Comment: Please see the update in the original post

Comment: Did you change `makepkg.conf` (or something else)? Also: `balena-cli-11.30.1.tgz` is the source file, not the built package.

Comment: @Stefan no changes were made to `makepkg.conf` and I've added inspection of the other archive in the directory, too

Comment: I now repeated the `makepkg -si` and it said it would install the already built binaries with `pacman -U`, I entered my password, it installed everything and now it worked fine:`which balena` `/usr/bin/balena`

nice! Danke schoen! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with `yay` (so I don't know where the package will be located) but if you make the package with [`makepkg`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg) you can list the files that the package would install using `tar`, eg.

```
tar -tf balena-cli-11.30.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst | less
```

So the AUR package `balena-cli` should install the binary `/usr/bin/balena` as well as over 50.000 files into the directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/balena-cli/`. So if neither exists, you don't have the package installed.

The response `error: package 'balena-cli' was not found` also indicates that the package was not installed.

Comment: Please see the **Update** above

Comment: `yay` installs the package similarly. I found the binary `google-chrome-stable` in `/usr/bin` when installed using `yay google-chrome`